# MOSFET diode configuration expression for dynamic bias

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, diodes, semiconductors, pmos

I'm trying to think of an elegant way of analytically expressing the gate voltage as a function of time \$V_g(t)\$ (= \$V_d(t)\$) for the diode configured MOSFET below.

The sources VDD and V1 are constant. We can take the initial conditions to be \$V_g(t=0) = Vd(t=0) = V_{d0} \$ (i.e., the capacitor \$C1\$ is charged at \$VDD-V_{d0}\$).

[image: Diode-configured p-FET, with initial conditions Vgs(t=0) = Vds(t=0) = Vd0-V1]

I understand that this FET is in the saturation regime where:

$$ 
I_{ds}(t) = \frac{1}{2}K_p(V_{d}(t) - V_s - V_{th})^2 
$$

I also understand that the voltage of a discharging capacitor can be represented by:

$$ 
v_{cap}(t) = VDD - V_d(t)
$$

where

$$
V_d(t) = \frac{1}{C_1}\int^{t}_{0} I_{ds}(t)dt + V_{d0}
$$

However, it appears that the first and last expressions are circular in some sense. \$I_{ds}(t)\$ will approach zero as \$V_{ds} \rightarrow V_{th} \$ for an ideal MOSFET. I believe an additional expression for \$V_d(t)\$ or \$I_{ds}(t)\$ may be required to solve this. Any insight?

My next step would be to create some analytical approximation for a non-ideal MOSFET with leakage current (i.e., non-zero drain current in the cutoff regime, thus \$V_{ds} \rightarrow 0\$ rather than \$V_{th}\$).

Comment: few things: are you assuming V1 and VDD are constant values, thus solving the circuit for a stable state? is it the temporal features of the starting up process that your looking for? and please provide a bit more detail as to the dynamics of your cct.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, V1 and VDD are constant sources. The t=0 conditions are provided. I'm interested in the temporal function Vd(t). I've updated the question reflecting this.